# Integer do not update

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Foo

Dim Maestro            As Workbook 
Dim Libro_FormularioWB As Worksheet 
Dim Origen_Datos       As String


Dim i             As String 
Dim Carpeta       As String 
Dim Archivo       As String 
Dim Ruta          As String 
Dim Formato       As String 
Dim Errores       As Integer 
Dim Formulario    As String 
Dim Buscar_Cedula As Range 
Dim Cedula        As Integer

i           = 5 
Set Maestro = ThisWorkbook 
Carpeta     = ActiveWorkbook.Path 
Formato     = ".xlsm" 
Origen      = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a" & i) 
x           = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a" & i) 
Formulario  = Carpeta & "" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a" & i) & Formato 

Set Buscar_Cedula = Maestro.Sheets("Resultados").Range("b1:zz1")

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a" & i) <> "" 
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a" & i) > "" Then 
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Formulario 

        Windows(Origen & Formato).Activate 
        Range("B42:B53").Select 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 
        Selection.Copy 
        Windows("ARCHIVO MAESTRO.xlsm").Activate 
        Maestro.Sheets("Resultados").Select 
        Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(x, Buscar_Cedula, Buscar_Cedula, , 0, 1).Offset(1, 0).Select 
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste := xlPasteValues, Operation := xlNone, 
        SkipBlanks _ := False, Transpose := False 
        Windows(Origen & Formato).Close SAVECHANGES := False

        On Error Resume Next 
        i = i + 1 
        Errores = Errores + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

i have the folowing code to search and opne a file from a list of values (id numbers) copy an specific range of cells, go back to the main workbook and past it. this loop already works, but i defined an integer as i and it do not update, so the code repeats on the same range.

origen should change as the integer growes 1 by 1, but it reminds the same.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next ` <-- Don't do this.

Comment: You're only setting `Origen` outside the loop, so it will not update when you change `i`

Comment: Your `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a" & i) > "" Then` is missing an `End if` but you have a `Loop` for your `While` - so the code you've posted doesn't even compile.

Comment: Are these 4 workbooks the same workbook: `Maestro, Windows("ARCHIVO MAESTRO.xlsm"), ThisWorkbook, ActiveWorkbook`? If not, please elaborate. What is the name of the worksheet in the source workbooks (`Origen & Formato`)?

Comment: You've defined `i` as a string, but are using it as a number.  The `_` is a line continuation character, but you've not put it at the end of the line.  `Paste:=xlPasteValues` not `Paste := xlPasteValues`... no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

### Import Data From Closed Workbooks

**Assumptions**

- You have a list of the source base names (file names without extension) in column `A` starting in row `5` of sheet `Data`.
- The same names can be found in `B1:ZZ1` of sheet `Resultados`.
- You want to open the files in the same path as the path of the workbook containing this code, and containing the previously mentioned sheets.
- When you open a file, you want to copy the values from the single-column range `B42:B53` of the sheet, I've chosen `Sheet1` (adjust it!), to sheet `Resultados` under the correct header.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DST_NAMES_SHEET As String = "Data"
    Const DST_NAMES_FIRST_CELL As String = "A5"
    Const DST_RESULTS_SHEET As String = "Resultados"
    Const DST_HEADERS_RANGE As String = "B1:ZZ1"
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1" ' ADJUST!!!
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "B42:B53"
    Const SRC_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsm"
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' I'm assuming that the following are all the same workbook:
    ' Maestro, Windows("ARCHIVO MAESTRO.xlsm"), ThisWorkbook, ActiveWorkbook
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dnws As Worksheet: Set dnws = dwb.Sheets(DST_NAMES_SHEET)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dnws.Range(DST_NAMES_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim dlCell As Range:
    Set dlCell = dnws.Cells(dnws.Rows.Count, dfCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim dnrg As Range: Set dnrg = dnws.Range(dfCell, dlCell)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_RESULTS_SHEET)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_HEADERS_RANGE)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = dws.Range(SRC_RANGE).Rows.Count
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = dwb.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    ' Open each file and copy the range.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, dnCell As Range, dcIndex
    Dim sFilePath As String, sBaseName As String
    
    For Each dnCell In dnrg.Cells
        sBaseName = CStr(dnCell.Value)
        sFilePath = sPath & sBaseName & SRC_FILE_EXTENSION
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if workbook doesn't exist
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If swb Is Nothing Then ' source file not found; workbook not opened
            MsgBox "File """ & sFilePath & """ not found.", vbCritical
        Else ' source file found; workbook opened
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if worksheet doesn't exist
                Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SRC_SHEET)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If sws Is Nothing Then ' source worksheet not found
                MsgBox "Worksheet """ & SRC_SHEET & """ not found.", vbCritical
            Else ' source worksheet found
                Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
                dcIndex = Application.Match(sBaseName, drg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(dcIndex) Then ' source base name found
                    drg.Cells(dcIndex).Offset(1) _
                        .Resize(rCount).Value = srg.Value
                'Else ' source base name not found among the headers
                End If
                Set sws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
            End If
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set swb = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next dnCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```